# Giving Dynamic ids to select tag which are created under a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I am sending a list of list from python backend to html page and creating dropdowns. as it is a list of list i am creating these using for loop in html so when created in for loop select tag will bear only a single id under which only all my select tags are created.

I don't know what is the number of list being sent from the backend so select tags should be created dynamically can i assign them dynamic id so that i can fetch the required values of that dropdown when required.

Below is my code

```
 {% for result in list1 %}
 <tr>
   <form id="listOfSearch{{result.0}}" method="post" action="/fetch_candid/">
    <td>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['listOfSearch{{result.0}}'].submit();">{{result.0}}<input name="uniqID" value="{{result.0}}" id="IdField" type="hidden" ></a></td>

    <input  name="save" value="0" type="hidden">

    <input  name="listresult" value="{{list1}}" type="hidden">

     <input type="hidden" id="statusofresume123" name="statusofresume123" value="{{sres}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="Client1" name="Client1" value="{{client}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="ReqId1" name="ReqId1" value="{{reqid}}"> 
      <input type="hidden" id="only_skills" name="only_skills" value="{{only_skills}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="mbno" name="mbno" value="{{mbno}}">
     <input type="hidden" id="ReqId" name="ReqId" value="{{reqid4}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="Client" name="Client" value="{{client2}}">
       <input type="hidden" id="Name" name="Name" value="{{Name}}">
       <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="{{Date1}}">
       <input type="hidden" id="datepicker1" name="datepicker1" value="{{Date2}}">

    <form id="listOfSearch{{result.0}}" method="post" action="/fetch_candid/">



    <td style="padding:5px; width:50px;">


    <select style="padding:5px; width:102%;"  onchange="savestate({{result.0}});" class="select11" id="status8" name="status8" title="Choose Status" >
     <option id="status8"  name="status8" >{{result.1}}</option>


     {% if result.1 == "HR_Interview" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "Internal_Interview" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">HR_Interview</option>
      <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "COL" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">CS</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "CI" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">CIS</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "CIS" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">Joining</option>



     {% elif result.1 == "CS" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">CI</option>


      {% elif result.1 == "Line_up" %}

      <option id="status8"  name="status8">Internal_Interview</option>
       <option id="status8"  name="status8">HR_Interview</option>
       <option id="status8"  name="status8">COL</option>

      {% else %}     

     {% endif %}

      </select> 

       <input class="css_save1" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick = "function9();">
```

hope you understood my question and thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question. Your asking about how to implement your approach while there may be a much simpler one to your problem.

Comment: Why do you need IDs on the dynamic elements?

Comment: @abstractpaper my approach is that i want to generate a pop up only when col is selected from the dropdown but as multiple select tags are created into a same id if i try to select using jscript only the value of first dropdown is fetched

Comment: @Barmar i need dynamic ids to fetch their respective values using jscript

Comment: @Gangadhar well it makes sense since ids in HTML are unique, an `id` attribute for a tag element cannot be shared with any other element in your entire page.

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly than i think you are looking for dynamic id for every select element than you can do this

```
<select style="padding:5px; width:102%;"  onchange="savestate({{result.0}});" class="select11" id="status8" name="status8" title="Choose Status" id="select"+result.id >
```

Sorry i do not know syntax of concatenation in python but you can append the id in loop.